# Java Sphinx Dynamically Set Grammar Rules

Tags: java, sphinx4

I am working on a project using the Sphinx library and I wanted to dynamically modify the grammar rules. For example, say I want to add the rule `open (Safari|Firefox)`, but I wanted to add it only after something happens. I didn't think this was possible until I came across this comment in the `JSGFGrammer` source file:

> Unlike a JSAPI recognizer, the JSGF Grammar only maintains one
>   Rule Grammar. This restriction may be relaxed in the future. The
>   grammar should not be modified while a recognition is in process
>   The call to JSGFGrammar.loadJSGF will load in a completely new
>   grammar, tossing any old grammars or changes. No call to commitChanges
>   is necessary (although such a call would be harmless in this
>   situation). RuleGrammars can be modified via calls to
>   RuleGrammar.setEnabled and RuleGrammar.setRule). In order for these
>   changes to take place, JSGFGrammar.commitChanges must be called after
>   all grammar changes have been made.

I attempted to add this to my construction of the Sphinx-related objects:

```
public SphinxBridge() {
        this.cm = new ConfigurationManager(SphinxBridge.class.getResource("input.config.xml"));
        this.recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
        this.microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");

        try {
            JSGFGrammar grammar = (JSGFGrammar) cm.lookup("jsgfGrammar");
            grammar.getRuleGrammar().setRule("test", new JSGFRule(), true);
            grammar.commitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        recognizer.allocate();
    }
```

I want to add the word `test` as a rule, so it would recognize it. However, when I start, I get a NullPointerException leading to the lookup line pertaining to `jsgfGrammar`. How do I correctly go about doing this?

---

**Update 1**:

After doing some tweaking, I am now getting an NPE on this line:

```
grammar.getRuleGrammar().setRule("test", new JSGFRule(), true);
```

I did some testing, and it turns out `getRuleGrammar()` is returning null. What do I do?

---

**Update 2**:

I have discovered that I can get rid of the NPE by allocating the grammar. However, I now get this exception:

```
edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.JSGFGrammarException: Unknown rule type
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.JSGFRuleGrammar.resolveRule(JSGFRuleGrammar.java:459)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.JSGFRuleGrammar.resolveAllRules(JSGFRuleGrammar.java:396)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.JSGFRuleGrammarManager.linkGrammars(JSGFRuleGrammarManager.java:62)
    at edu.cmu.sphinx.jsgf.JSGFGrammar.commitChanges(JSGFGrammar.java:618)
    at me.nrubin29.jtalk.SphinxBridge.<init>(SphinxBridge.java:28)
```

This is the new code:

```
public SphinxBridge() {
        this.cm = new ConfigurationManager(SphinxBridge.class.getResource("input.config.xml"));
        this.recognizer = (Recognizer) cm.lookup("recognizer");
        this.microphone = (Microphone) cm.lookup("microphone");

        try {
            JSGFGrammar grammar = (JSGFGrammar) cm.lookup("jsgfGrammar");
            grammar.allocate();
            grammar.getRuleGrammar().setRule("test", new JSGFRule(), true); // "test" is the name.
            grammar.commitChanges();
        }
        catch (Exception e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

        recognizer.allocate();
    }
```

Comment: Lookup returns null because there is no such component in the XML configuration file.

Comment: JSGFRule is just an abstract class, you need some subclass like JSGFRuleToken or JSGFRuleAlternatives.